# How to define a Groovy function which accepts parametrized closure as a parameter?

Tags: groovy

I want to define a function, which accepts another function (closure) as a parameter.
The second function should accept 1 parameter.

Currently, I have just a simple signature:

```
def func1(func2) {
   func2("string")
}
```

Is there a way to explicitly specify, that `func2` should accept 1 parameter (or less)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not in the definition of `func1`, but [you can check](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/Closure.html#getMaximumNumberOfParameters%28%29) the `maximumNumberOfParameters` for a Closure at runtime, like so:

```
def func1( func2 ) {
  if( func2.maximumNumberOfParameters > 1 ) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException( 'Expected a closure that could take 1 parameter or less' )
  }
  func2( 'string' )
}
```

Testing success:

```
def f2 = { a -> "returned $a" }
assert func1( f2 ) == 'returned string'
```

And failure:

```
def f3 = { a, b -> "returned $a" }
try {
  func1( f3 )
  assert true == false // Shouldn't get here
}
catch( e ) {
  assert e.message == 'Expected a closure that could take 1 parameter or less'
}
```

Comment: I prefer test exceptions with [shouldFail](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/util/GroovyTestCase.html#shouldFail(java.lang.Class,%20groovy.lang.Closure)) method

Comment: @ArturoHerrero Very good point... but I'd have to wrap my tiny example in a class extending GroovyTestCase :-(